# Missing template with Devise custom registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When using recaptcha for Devise I have to make a new custom registrations controller and my issue is I get a missing template error when their is an error for the email, password or password confirmation because its hitting a route that doesn't even exist.

```
Template is missing

Missing template registrations/new
```

The recaptcha works on its own error and renders back to the same page but not for the others.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    if verify_recaptcha
        super
    else
        flash.delete :recaptcha_error
        build_resource
        clean_up_passwords(resource)
        flash[:alert] = "There was an error with the recaptcha code below."
        render :template => '/devise/registrations/new'  
    end
  end
end

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

It should be hitting the same page the recaptcha does on errors (`'/devise/registrations/new'`)How do I correct this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try moving the templates from `/views/devise/registrations` to just `/views/registrations`.  (And changing the reference in your code from /devise/registrations/new to just /registrations/new.)

Comment: Yeah, this was a simple solution, thank you I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to your `config/application.rb` file

`config.paths['app/views'] << 'app/views/devise'`